# Generic LERP for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I want a generic linear interpolation function for Unity.
It should work for
***float, Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Color, Quaternion***

Lerping requires this logic.

```
static T LerpGeneric<T>(T a, T b, float t)
{
    return a * (1f - t) + b * t;
}
```

ofcourse  it does not compile, and I'm not sure if this logic also works for Quaternions or not.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: No because you can't just assume that all types implementing a `Lerp` use the same underlying math ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do this currently. .Net generics are not like c++ templates, so you need to use a generic constraint if you want specific methods to be usable. Unfortunately no such interfaces are available for the built in types.

Providing functionality like this has been proposed multiple times. The latest would be [generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/), but this is only in *preview* in [.Net 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6). I would assume that .Net 6 is not yet supported by Unity3d.

A workaround could be to delegate the add and multiply methods to delegates, i.e.

```
public LerpGeneric<T>(T a, T b, float t, Func<T, T, T> mul, Func<T, T, T> add) 
    => add(mul(a , (1f - t)) , Mul(b , t));
```

But this would likely just be more complicated than providing individual implementation for each type. So I would probably just bite the bullet and provide 6 implementations. In practice it would not be a lot of code, so the maintenance overhead should be minimal.

Quaternions usually have a [Lerp implementation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html), since that is one of the major reasons to use quaternions in the first place. Unity3ds vectors and colors also have lerp-implementations already provided, and for floats you have [Mathf.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html).

Answer (score 1):

I also had this question, but no time to deep researchig or ugly programming. Personally I do this, a fast and simple copy-paste that is simple, elegant and work as a charm:

```
    public abstract class Swapper<T>
    {
        public T Start;
        public T End;
        UnityAction<T> Callback;
        public abstract void LerpValue(float amount);
        public abstract void UnlerpValue(float amount);
    }
    
    public class ValueSwapper : Swapper<float>
    {
        public override void LerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Mathf.Lerp(StartValue, EndValue, amount));
        }

        public override void UnlerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Mathf.Lerp(EndValue, StartValue, amount));
        }
    }
    
    public class Vector2Swapper : Swapper<Vector2>
    {
        public override void LerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Vector2.Lerp(StartValue, EndValue, amount));
        }

        public override void UnlerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Vector2.Lerp(EndValue, StartValue, amount));
        }
    }
    
    public class Vector3Swapper : Swapper<Vector3>
    {
        public override void LerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Vector3.Lerp(StartValue, EndValue, amount));
        }

        public override void UnlerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Vector3.Lerp(EndValue, StartValue, amount));
        }
    }
    
    public class Vector4Swapper : Swapper<Vector4>
    {
        public override void LerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Vector4.Lerp(StartValue, EndValue, amount));
        }

        public override void UnlerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Vector4.Lerp(EndValue, StartValue, amount));
        }
    }
    
    public class ColorSwapper : Swapper<Color>
    {
        public override void LerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Color.Lerp(StartValue, EndValue, amount));
        }

        public override void UnlerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Color.Lerp(EndValue, StartValue, amount));
        }
    }
    
    public class QuaternionSwapper : Swapper<Quaternion>
    {
        public override void LerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Quaternion.Lerp(StartValue, EndValue, amount));
        }

        public override void UnlerpValue(float amount)
        {
            Callback.Invoke(Quaternion.Lerp(EndValue, StartValue, amount));
        }
    }
```

This is an example of usage:

```
    QuaternionSwapper sp = new QuartenionSwapper();
    sp.Start = startQuaternion;
    sp.End = EndQuaternion;
    sp.Callback = (qt) => targetQuaternion = qt;

    public IEnumerator SomeCoroutine(int steps,Swapper sp)
    {
        float step = 1f / steps;
   
        for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            sp.LerpValue(amount);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
   }
```